# não consigo trocar a cor da janela e do frame usando o customtkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from customtkinter import *
import tkinter


janela = CTk()

class Aplication:
    def __init__(self):
        self.janela = janela
        self.tela()
        self.frames_Da_tela()
        janela.mainloop()

    def tela(self):
        self.janela.title('Cadastro de Clientes')
        self.janela.geometry('700x500')
        self.janela.config(background='#446C65')     # <------- não muda a cor de fundo da janela
        self.janela.resizable(True, True)
        self.janela.maxsize(width= 900, height= 700)
        self.janela.minsize(width= 500, height= 300)
```

ele não retorna erro, porém não muda a cor

```
    def frames_Da_tela(self):
        self.frame_1 = CTkFrame(master=self.janela, bg='446C65', border_width= 3, border_color='#ACACAC') # <---- bg não altera a cor de fundo do frame
        self.frame_1.place(relx= 0.02, rely=0.02, relwidth= 0.96, relheight= 0.46)
Aplication()
```

aqui ele retorna erro

Comment: Testei aqui e funcionou, você faz alguma configuração em outro local?